# Vertical-floating elements in CSS?

Tags: html, css, html-lists, floating

Is there any solution for my problem, described in this image?

[image: http://i.imgur.com/6uhxlNm.png]

I have a DIV-tag with a fixed height.
In this element, i have a List.
This List should be floated like columns.
The list-elements have a fixed width.
if there are "too much" elements in the Div-Tag, it should scroll horizontally.
The amount of columns and elements is not fix.
It should also work in old Browsers.

Is there any solution with HTML/CSS?

Comment: Have a play with the display (CSS).

Comment: Please post up what code (if any) that you have tried so far.

Comment: Interesting :) I've created a fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/y93pZ/ for anyone to use since I'm wondering if this is possible with CSS only.

Comment: Are the list-elements fixed height? Can you add containers? Because then floating them (or inline-block) is enough

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `columns` and related CSS3 properties:

Here is fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DeLL7/5/

Updated for for non-fixed number of columns and fixed container height. However, for older browsers, you're probably out of luck, without having to "manually" arrange the boxes.

Comment: for older browsers you can try this polyfill [BetleyWhitehorne/CSS3MultiColumn · GitHub](https://github.com/BetleyWhitehorne/CSS3MultiColumn)

Comment: This also doesn't work in IE10, btw. (even though it's supposed to support columns, I believe)

Comment: Microsoft says it should work in IE10:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673534(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: In IE10 there are indeed columns but they're all messed up. What a surprise.