# Html/Css Vertical classification of blog's posts

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I want my blog's post(33%width) to be floated from top to bottom, and when they rich the end of the content (static height), to continue again from top to bottom beside the rest of them. I have already made this static web page with columns(link is in the jsfiddle project).

There is a simple static example, of what i am talking about, here :http://jsfiddle.net/KBX5B/1/

```
<div id="content"><div>
```

But I want it to be automated (not to pass left and top values for each post) with pure html/css. I would like not to mess Javascript, but if you think it's the only way i would like to know about it.

I am sorry for my bad English and I do appreciate your time.

Comment: What exactly that fiddle has to do with what you are asking?

Comment: It shows the desireable output. Dont look the code, but the output. I was not sure if i could make you understand, what i want to do, with plain english. Sorry for trouble.

Comment: I still dont see how that fiddle relates to the question, sorry. But it seems what you are looking for is something like the css property `column-count`

Comment: I am totally sorry. I have updated the link. Check now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use `column-count` or `column-width` properties to achieve what you want. Will only work on modern browsers. IE10 included.

http://jsfiddle.net/KBX5B/2/

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found the solution after reading MANY Posts...
Here it is :)

[Vertical-floating elements in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15768794/vertical-floating-elements-in-css)